# How to change Rs to Indian rupee symbol (Devanagari letter "र") at product display page?

Tags: magento-1.7, price

I am changing Rs to Indian rupee sign (Devanagari letter "र") . using below code

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new'); ?>
```

replace it by

```
<?php
$string = $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new');
$string = str_replace("Rs", "<img src='http://www.myiris.com/insurance/images/rupee_icon.gif'>", $string);
echo $string; 
?>
```

Problem: In some products there are custom options like color or model etc where rupee sign is not changing.

I changed rupee sign by changing in below file.    public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

**For custom option products where should i changed code? filename**

for reference

1. http://www.ultimatespares.com/rizoma-grips-legend.html -- without sign
2. http://www.ultimatespares.com/brands/k-n/k-n-kn-303-oil-filter.html --with sign

Answer (score 2):

Don't change code at all. In the admin panel, go to `System > Manage Currency > Symbols`. There you should see all currencies used by your store and you can change their symbol.

But you should use the Unicode character <kbd>**₹**</kbd> instead of a GIF.

Indian Currency symbol unicode  : `&#x20b9;`

Comment: i dont want unicode character. i want  Devanagari letter "र" .

Comment: It's probably possible to enter HTML as a symbol too, i.e. your `<img>` tag, but I never tried that.

Comment: For custom option products where should i changed code? filename

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you, its a little work around if you dont want to use Unicode for rupee symbol,( ** dont change rupee symbol to unicode, let it be default)

**include this style in your css**

```
<style >
@font-face {
    font-family: 'rupee';
    src: url('rupee_foradian-1-webfont.eot');
    src: local('Ã¢ËœÂº'), url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,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)
    format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

And below write a small `JS` that will select the element with price tag and will apply the desired output.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $(".price").text(function(){
       return $(this).text().replace("Rs","R");
    });

    $(".price").css({'font-family':'rupee','font-size':'20px'});

});
</script>
```

I have tested it , and its working perfectly for me.

**PS : But I personally recommend using `unicode` in currency symbol setting**

Comment: thanks @n01ze. but i just want filename where i should get code of Rs. so i will change. just check my urls.

Comment: ok @PrashantTapase you are welcome

Comment: Yup I too know, anyways the above code I gave will give you the desired output :)

Comment: can u help with the filename? http://www.ultimatespares.com/rizoma-grips-legend.html -- without sign...

Comment: enable the template hinting and check first , where it is coming from

Comment: i already checked and done changes. thats why it is coming on other product page but not on that product page where custom option (option to set color ) is present.