# Indian Rupee Symbol not showing only for Windows OS

Tags: price, ce-1.9.0.1

I was spend few hours on googling for showing the ₹ instated of **Rs.**. I have found mostly a common answer. And try each of theme but its not worked for me.

**My approached  :**

First I have followed the following answer

[How to change Rs to Indian rupee symbol](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73597/3368)

Its showing ₹ symbol on Linux system but not showing on Windows system. Then I tried an alternative method.

1. Download this JS file from [here](http://vivacityinfotech.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/rupee.js) and upload to root/js folder.
2. Open file `app/design/frontend/default/YOUR THEME/layout/page.xml`
3. And add a new line `<action method=”addJs”><script>rupee.js</script></action> after  <block type=”page/html_head” name=”head” as=”head”>.`
4. Open a file `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml`

   and find code < symbol >Rs < /symbol > and replace it with < symbol >Rs. < /symbol >

And also use < symbol >₹< /symbol > instead of < symbol >Rs< /symbol >

***But finally I'm failed***

I will be Appreciate for your help.

Comment: try this : `&#x20b9;`

Comment: I have update my question .Please check again.

Comment: Your js file added in the page??view pagesource  and check

Comment: I have checked. its always   loads on the head.

Comment: Were you able to get rupee symbol working on windows os?

Comment: yup. if put rupee symbols in back-end its working file except windows 7 or below.

Comment: use indian rupee fonts to fix this issue . Im using fonts especially for displaying ₹ :: like this   1000 <span class='indian-rupee">Rs</span> Only .Ths will work fine across all browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens due to the issue in Windows. Windows 7 and 8 does not have support for new Indian currency symbol by default, so they have issued an update for client systems to display this symbol correctly. You can find it [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2496898)

Now, since this is for clients only, I still don't know how to display this symbol for clients who does not have support for this symbol. :(